# Google Cast AAC 5.1 Audio

Tags: ios, google-cast

I am having some difficulty with my (in development) iOS Google Cast v3 app + default receiver application when trying to play mp4+aac. It would seem that stereo works, but 5.1 does not.

**The following format combination works perfectly**

"h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]"

"aac (mp4a / 0x6134706d), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127690 bit/s"

**The following format combination does not**

"h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]"

"aac (mp4a / 0x6134706d), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 340852 bit/s"

---

As above, I'm not using a custom receiver, which means I'm not using the Media Player Library.

Do I need a custom receiver and media player library to make this work? Do I need to pass in some specific information about the audio codec when setting up the stream? I presently provide the video/mp4 mimetype.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Hey @LeonNicholls I have attempted on both a first and second generation Chromecast - but not on an Ultra. Also the link you sent to me appears to be for an internal google link - would you mind pleas confirming if I should be able to access that URL?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69088762#comment4